# Exit frame and panel from panel method

Tags: wxpython, panel, frame

I have a wxPython frame, with a Panel. In my Panel class, I have a method which is called when a button on that panel is pressed. How can I close the Frame, and the containing panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches. Assuming that the panel's parent is the frame, you could do this as the button's handler:

```
def onClose(self, event):
   frame = self.GetParent()
   frame.Close()
```

Or you could use pubsub to "publish" a message to the frame class and tell it to close. See the following article fora simple example of pubsub: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/